# Creating Kubernetes Pod per Kubernetes Job and Cleanup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to create Kubernetes job with the following requirements:

1. Only one pod can be created for each job at most
2. If the pod failed - the job will fail
3. Max run time of the pod will be 1 hour
4. If the job finished successfully - delete the job

I tried the following configurations:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          image: {{ .Values.image }}
          env:
            - name: ARG1
              value: {{ required "ARG1 is mandatory" .Values.ENV.ARG1 }}
            - name: GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
              value: {{ .Values.ENV.GITLAB_USER_EMAIL }}
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 1
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 3600
```

But it's not working as expected, any ideas?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Only one pod can be created for each job at most

The requested parallelism (.spec.parallelism) can be set to any non-negative value. If it is unspecified, it defaults to 1. If it is specified as 0, then the Job is effectively paused until it is increased.

> For Cronjobs could be helpful `successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0, failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0`  this will
> remove the PODs if it's get **failed** or **success** so no history or
> POD will stays. So only one pod will get created or run.

- If the pod failed - the job will fail

That will be the default behavior, also `restartPolicy: Never` so it won't get restarted.

- Max run time of the pod will be 1 hour

  `activeDeadlineSeconds: 3600` you have already added
- If the job finished successfully - delete the job

`ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100` will solve your issue.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          image: {{ .Values.image }}
          env:
            - name: ARG1
              value: {{ required "ARG1 is mandatory" .Values.ENV.ARG1 }}
            - name: GITLAB_USER_EMAIL
              value: {{ .Values.ENV.GITLAB_USER_EMAIL }}
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 1
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 3600
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm not sure but i think that `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` configurations are related to Cronjobs only no?

Comment: even i have not used with job specifically but used with cronjobs. in backend cronjobs create the Job only at end so it should work. you can try applying yaml once and check but i think it will work

Comment: Its not working for Job AFAIK, just tried it :(

Comment: `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` is the way, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs

Comment: Thanks, note this feature is enabled In Kubernetes v1.21